# Finding the most repeated value using table() function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I was given a sample vector v and was asked to use `R` code to extract, as a number (meaning: not as a character string), the value that was repeated the most times in `v`.

(Hints: use `table()`; note that `which.max()` gives you index of a vector's maximum value, like the maximum value within a table; `names()` allows you the extract the values of the original vector, when applied to the output of `table()`.)

*My answer is as follows:*
**names(which.max(table(v)))**

it returns the correct answer as a string, not as a number. Am i using the hint correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just wrap the result in `as.numeric` - `as.numeric(names(which.max(table(v))))`

Answer (score 1):

`names` return the number as character, perhaps add `as.integer`/`as.numeric` to convert it to number.

```
as.integer(names(which.max(table(v))))
```

Moreover, in case of tie `which.max` would return only the first maximum. If you want all the values which are tied you can use :

```
v <- c(1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3)
as.integer(names(which.max(table(v))))
#[1] 1


tab <- table(v)
as.integer(names(tab[max(tab) == tab]))
#[1] 1 3
```